# UIView not shows round

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners

For making a circular `UIView` I am using the `cornerRadius` property.

I have a UIView with dimension 79*158.

```
redView.layer.cornerRadius = redView.frame.size.height/2
redView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

It shows elipse instead of circle:

[image: It shows elipse instead of circle]

Any workaround or does it only work with square type (eg. UIView(100*100))?

I am ok if it resizes dynamically.

Comment: How can be a rectangle shape view become a circle? You need some mathematics.

Comment: To make a view round, you have to create it square first

Comment: Can't we make center Fit ? or shrink, etc. ?

Comment: Use `width/2` instead of `height/2` if the view is taller than wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this...

```
    func makeCircle (view: UIView) {
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        let height = view.frame.size.height
        let width = view.frame.size.width
        let newHeight = min(height, width) // use "max" if you want big circle

        var rectFrame = view.frame
        rectFrame.size.height = newHeight
        rectFrame.size.width = newHeight
        view.frame = rectFrame
        view.layer.cornerRadius = newHeight/2
    }
```

use like this:

```
@IBOutlet var rectView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        makeCircle(view: rectView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

can't.
Try resize `UIView` to square: 79*79 OR 158*158

And set:

```
redView.layer.cornerRadius = redView.frame.size.height/2
```

Comment: OK!, Any workaround like make it center fit/ AspectFit ? I am ok if it resizes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You have a UIView with dimension 79*158.So that is wrong. You should have exactly **same height and width** for rounding exact a view to circle shape.

**E.g.**

```
redView.frame.size.height = 79.0
redView.frame.size.width = 79.0
```

**or**

```
redView.frame.size.height = 158.0
redView.frame.size.width = 158.0
```

And apply corner radius like:

```
  redView.clipsToBounds = true
  redView.layer.cornerRadius = redView.frame.size.height / 2.0
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Note**: Check your constrains also If you are using Auto Layout. Be sure view frame doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraints then changing the frame/bounds of the view is not a good idea. Instead you should do the following.

1. If the view is contained in a `UIViewController` then set the `cornerRadius` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method
2. And if the view is itself a subclass of `UIView` the set the `cornerRadius` in `layoutSubviews` method

Answer (score 0):

Only Squire view make a perfect circle. For example, if your view size is (10*10),(50*50),(100*100), etc. then your view becomes perfect squire else not.

Answer (score 0):

Using IBDesignable, you can display without project run in storyboard ox .XIB  **#simple way**

**Step 1.** Subclass UIView:

```
@IBDesignable class RoundedCornerView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

@IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor = UIColor.orangeGradientLight {
    didSet {
        layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
}
}
```

**Step 2.** Set custom class in identity inspector:

[image]